# Use JWT to authorize microservices

Tags: java, jwt, authorization, microservices

I'm trying to build a reservation system for a sports hall. I have divided it into multiple microservices, such as Equipment and Location. One of them is called *"Authentication"*, where I check the user's credentials. There I have a UserDetailsService where I check whether the user exists and what role it has.

I am using JWT (io.jsonwebtoken more precisely), and I have a request filter that checks if the token is valid. So, right now the authorization works for the authentication, but I'm not sure how to pass the JWT token to the other microservices and authorize them as well.

I was thinking of simply calling that filter form *Authentication* in each microservices whenever I need something, but then I believe that defeats the purpose of having microservices.

Is there a better alternative? How do I actually check the JWT token in those microservices?

Comment: you can work either with a shared secret (symmetric key, HS256) or, better, use RS256 or similar, sign with the private key only known by the auth service and validate with the public key, known by all services. The public key can be provided via an endpoint as a JWK (JSON Web Key)

Comment: What platform are you using—Spring? Micronaut?

Comment: I am using Spring and H512 to sign the key, but is it enough if I just check in each microservice that the token is valid?

Comment: Hi it does sound strange to have an authentication service. Basically if you are accessing protected API endpoints then each service should do its own validation. Otherwise I don't see how this is secure. Each service will need to have its own configuration of a trusted JWT issuer and then do the validation.

Comment: But in that case, don't you end up with code duplication and technically dependencies because they use almost the same code?